# definite integral involving Bessel function and Airy function

Tags: integration

I want to find a closed-form expression (if exists any) for the integral

$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}p \,p^2 J(1, ap)\,\mathrm{Ai}(b-p^2)$,

where $J(1,ap)$ is the Bessel function of first order with argument $ap$, and $a$ and $b$ are real constants.

I got a series by repeatedly integrating by parts with the help of the antiderivatives of the Airy function. The series, if truncated, gives a good approximation for small $a$, but it does not converge for large $a$. Is there any way I can numerically evaluate this integral for any $a$, or find a closed-form expression for it?

Comment: The COMMA in the Bessel function is needed!

Comment: No, it is the Bessel function of first order with argument a*p! Mathematica: BesselJ[1,ap]

Comment: Then you shall write $J(1, ap)$!

Comment: I thought Abramowitz and Stegun used $J_1(x)$.

Comment: Yes, but we need to know what you write :)